# Inserting into database php variables

Tags: php, sql

I have got this code:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$method = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['method']);

$method1 = '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', explode("\n", $description)) . '</li></ul>';


mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipe (title, description, method) VALUES('".$title."', '".$description."', '".$method1."')");
```

But it isnt adding anything to my database. Should this code be working?

UPDATE*******

I have added the following code but it is not outputing anything

```
if($success)
{
echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
}
else
{
echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Try the query directly in phpmyadmin or your console to see the error.

Comment: I tried the query in phpmyadmin and it worked? INSERT INTO recipe (title, description, method) VALUES('".$title."', '".$description."', '".$method1."')

Comment: That might because you aren't entering the same query; PHP would translate $title to the value of $title.  What I usually do (as a lazy solution) would be to write $query="bla bla"; and then use $result=mysql_query($query); -- you can 'echo query;' to see what the actual query you're generating is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap your fields with `''`

```
"INSERT INTO recipe (`title`, `description`, `method`) VALUES('".$title."', '".$description."', '".$method1."')");
```

look on [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

`'` and `"` are inverted in `VALUES()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not need `(title, description, method)` if you insert the fields in the correct order.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO recipe VALUES ('".$title."', '".$description."', '".$method1."')";

mysql_query($query);
```

If the problem is not resolved, try the query directly in phpmyadmin or your console to see the error.

Comment: in case this table is contain only those 3 fields